# Your global Angular CLI version is greater than your local version. To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false"

Tags: angular, version

When we run angular project i got this message :
Your global Angular CLI version (8.1.3) is greater than your local
version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

> ng serve -o
>   Your global Angular CLI version (8.1.3) is greater than your local
>   version (7.3.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

This is a warning due to version

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 6):

This is because of version mismatch
To avoid issues:
use

> npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to solve this global and local angular CLI version issue.
1. Keep a specific angular-cli version for both environments.
2. Goto latest angular-cli version for both environments.

**1. Specific angular-cli version** (use when working with existing application)

First, find out which angular version you want to keep on the global and local environment.

```
ng --version
```

**for example:** here we keeping local angular CLI version 7.3.9

So, we have to change the global version also on 7.3.9.
use cmd>

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@7.3.9 -g
```

here, '-g' flag for a set global angular-cli version.

**2. Goto latest angular version for both CLI environment.**(use when creating new application)

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest -g  
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: This Code 
`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest -g  
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest ` 
work for me but you most to specify the version code... 
For example for me the version is 11.2.7
I do 
`npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@11.2.7 -g  
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@11.2.7 `